# iOS Custom Control

Tags: iphone, ios5, uicontrol

I am building a custom control that looks like the one in the image below.

[image]

It will basically be a menu with a slider. The arrows will allow me to change the three days show on the slider track. Acoording to the day I select with the slider I want to change some views on the main screen (this menu will on the bottom of my page). So basically this is the only thing that I will "listen" in my main controller: if some day has been selected.

I have figured out all the code I will have to write, but I am not sure wether I should subclass UIControl or UIView. And if so, where should I write the code of my controller (changing the days, adding the drag effec, etc ) in the UIControl (UIView)? Or should I subclass UIViewController, and write there all the code there. (but if so, why should I subclass UIControl (UIView) in the first way).

So basically I want to know what extra files I need to create, besides the view interface of my custom control(which I did in the IB), where should I put the code (IBOutlets, IBAction methods) and how do I communicate with the main view controller (I set the main controller as a delegate of my custom control?).

Sorry for the long post.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to subclass `UIControl`. Users of this control can do `[yourControl addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlValueChanged];` to react to changed values. In your control, when you have determined that a new day has been selected, you call `[self sendActionsForControlsEvents:UIControlValueChanged];` and voila, all interested classes will get informed.

Keep that control as self-contained as possible. This means, only give it as much logic as you need to, and nothing more. Think about how you use Apple provided UI elements: try to make yours as generic (if practical; use common sense here). In short: you should thrive to make this control generic enough that it could be useful to you in other projects or other places of your app.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have one more question, in which method of my control should I add my initialization code(for instance if I want to create a UIGestureRecognizer).

Comment: You will have more success posting that as a separate question. Cheers.

Comment: @Cosmin: if the gesture recognizer is important for the control (i.e. the control requires it for its functionality), then you'd initialize it in your control's `initWithFrame:`. Alternatively, if you have a different designated initializer you'd initialize the gesture recognizer there.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you should subclass [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and put all of the logic to draw the component and interact with the component there. `UIControl` inherits from `UIView` and adds target/action behavior. This way you can `sendAction:to:forEvents:` with `UIControlEventValueChanged` whenever the date changes.

You could alternatively implement a delegate protocol for when the user changes the selected date.

For example:

```
@protocol DateSliderDelegate <NSObject>
  - (void)dateSlider:(id)slider dateDidChange:(NSDate *)date fromDate:(NSDate *)oldDate;
@end
```

You don't want to use a `UIViewController` since it's job is to manage higher-level views, like the screen that your widget is on. You'll use a view controller later when you are consuming your component and do things like set the date to display initially and listen for change events.